# Spring - Refactoring - move entity constant to configuration (application.properties)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, refactoring

What is the best way to move constant from code:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Post {

   ...

   private static final int HOTPOST_LIKE_TRESHOLD = 6;

   ...

   public long increaseLikeCounter() {
      likesCount++;

      if (likesCount >= HOTPOST_LIKE_TRESHOLD) {
         this.setStatus(HOT);
      }

      return likesCount;
   }

   ...

}
```

to configuration file using Spring? (i.e. Spring Boot application.properties)

Operation is now encapsulated in Post class, and it's OK for me to move HOTPOST_LIKE_TRESHOLD away from class, but I want to keep increaseLikeCounter method where it is.

Comment: Post shouldn't decide if it's considered hot - there should be another entity that encodes this rule, and you can have theshold as bean property there.

Comment: Ok, but what about other situations where Post should decide and it must use value that i want to move to configuration, but don't want to pass throug method parameter ?

The question is about technical possibility, rather than business rules.

What is the best way to use configurable properties in entities (not managed by spring) without passing it by method parameters.

Comment: Well, if we're discussing just a technical possibility, then you can autowire just about any object in Spring, just give it unique name.

Comment: Please check my comment below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979576/spring-refactoring-move-entity-constant-to-configuration-application-proper/45981912#comment78932032_45981912

Answer (score 4):

change post to:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Post {

   ...

   protected abstract Integer getHotpostLikeTreshold();    
   ...

   public long increaseLikeCounter() {
      likesCount++;

      if (likesCount >= getHotpostLikeTreshold()) {
         this.setStatus(HOT);
      }

      return likesCount;
   }
   ...

}
```

then extend the class, for example:

```
public class SimplePost extends Post {

@Value("${simplePost.hotpostLikeTreshold}")
private Integer hotpostLikeTreshold;

@Override
protected Integer getHotpostLikeTreshold(){
   return hotpostLikeTreshold;
}
...
```

in your **application.properties** add

```
simplePost.hotpostLikeTreshold = 6
```

EDIT:

```
use a Service and getters setters:

@Service
public class SimplePostService{

    // wire your property in
    @Value("${simplePost.hotpostLikeTreshold}")
    private Integer hotpostLikeTreshold;

    public Post savePost(...){
       Post post = new SimplePost(); // you create your post with 'new'
       ... 
       // set your property
       post.setHotpostLikeTreshold(this.hotpostLikeTreshold);
       ...
       // save your entity
       SimplePostDAO.save(post);
    }

}
```

Comment: We're discussing JPA @Entity objects here. They are not Spring beans. We're creating them using "new" operator (new SimplePost()) or accessing through EntityManager. How your soultion could work?

Comment: @msiakis, in this case, you have to externalize that configuration to a place where it can be autowired by Spring.